# windows 7 cmd hide fullscreen window

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-7, fullscreen

I have a cmd countdown script that minimize all windows, but not a fullscreen window (VLC media player). Is it possible to minimize / hide also the fullscreen window?

countdown.cmd

```
@echo off
set /p countdownminutes="Minutes: "
set /a countdownseconds = countdownminutes * 60
echo COUNTDOWN
echo %countdownminutes% Minutes
timeout /T %countdownseconds% /nobreak
powershell -command "(new-object -com shell.application).minimizeall()"
```

Please no solutions with third party software.

Answer (score 0):

You could change that last phrase, since this should be the equivalent of minimise all windows. However, in comments you say it is not enough to deactivate VLC in full screen, so I have added that step before your minimizeall.

```
@echo off
set /p countdownminutes="Minutes: "
set /a countdownseconds = countdownminutes * 60
echo COUNTDOWN
echo %countdownminutes% Minutes
timeout /T %countdownseconds% /nobreak

mshta.exe vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""SAPI.SpVoice"").Speak(""Minimising"")(window.close)")
mshta.exe vbScript:Execute("CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"").AppActivate(""VLC media player"", 0)(window.close)")
mshta.exe vbScript:Execute("CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"").SendKeys(""{F11}"")(window.close)")

powershell -command "(new-object -com shell.application).minimizeall()"
rem powershell -command "(New-Object -ComObject shell.application).toggleDesktop()"
```

Comment: Thanks. With this - `toggleDesktop()` - the taskbar and desktop widgets come to foreground and the Video play further in fullscreen. It's not perfect, but better than before.

Comment: This is not quite what is happening and not what is desired. So: Only 1 desktop. Many icons on desktop. VLC (video) play in fullscreen. With `minimizeall()` all windows are minimized, but the VLC stays in fullscreen. No visible `hint` happens. With `toggleDesktop()` it's a bit better: the taskbar + widgets (no icons) appear in the foreground (before the fullscreen). However, the VLC remains in fullscreen. A subsequent `minimizeall()` doesn't change the VLC. What is better with `toggleDesktop()` is that there is a visible *hint* when in fullscreen. No window should be closed. Only need a hint.